# Is there a way to query how much data a particular table or column is storing in sqlite?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-performance

I have a 50mb sqlite database. I would like to run a query or report to indicate which tables / columns / rows are storing how much data.

My purpose is to optimize how I am storing data to reduce the database footprint.

I am familiar with the vacuum command to shink the database. But I am interested in improving the compression of images and other data that I store and would like to be able to measure the result before and after as well as target my efforts where they will be most productive.

Any query or tool (free or otherwise) that can accomplish this would satisfy the question.

I am using sqlite3.

Comment: Wouldn't file system size after vacuum be a practical way to measure this?

Comment: Yes, for tables/columns/fields/rows that I know are taking the most space. Its a large enough schema that I would like to know where to look for areas of optimization. I might focus on one table / column, not realizing that another table is the real data hog.

Comment: I guess you'd have to vacuum before and after, which isn't exactly practical if you expect it to be active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sqlite3_analyzer`](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) shows how much space tables and indexes take up.

Comment: It's an awkward moment when I found that now we all use x64 linux but sqlite3's download page provides binary for x86 linux and windows, and no such package in Ubuntu, and no easy way to build :(

Comment: @tdihp To ask how to build `sqlite3_analyzer`, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I have successfully built sqlite3_analyzer. It's just not trivial as I expected. such a tool, much useful.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
SELECT SUM(len) FROM (
    SELECT length(column_name) AS len FROM table_name);
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I use it for identifying which columns are using the most space on a given table. I selected the answer from CL because it provides a complete listing for the entire database table by table. From there, if I need to do further research, I use the query you provided. Thank you for taking the time to post an answer.